# Could someone explain how $\int_a^b g(x) \ dx = L(f,P)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a Riemann integrable function on $[a,b]$. Let $P$ be a partition $a = t_0< t_1<\cdots<t_n = b$.  Let $g(x)$ be a step function defined as follows:

$$g(x) = \inf_{t \in [t_{i-1},t_i]} f(t)$$ for $ x \in (t_{i-1},t_i)$ with $g(t_i) = f(t_i)$. Then we have the $g \leq f$ and $\int_a^b g(x) = L(f,P)$ where $L(f,P)$ is the lower Darboux sum of $f$ with respect to $P$.

I understand why $g \leq f$, but I do not see from the definition of $L(f,P)$ why $\int_a^b g(x) = L(f,P)$  could someone break it down for me please

Comment: What is the definition of the lower Darboux sum you have?

Comment: These Riemann integral questions are always easier to understand drawn out. But if you can understand, the integral of that step function will just be the sum of the areas of the rectangles, since any given subdivision $[t_i, t_{i+1}]$ will still give the same infimum and supremum for each subdivision since $g$ is constant there.

Comment: $g$ is piecewise constant, so its integral is just the sum of the infimum on each interval times the interval's width, which is the definition of the lower Darboux sum.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying - What I don't get about the definition of $g$ is the $g(t_i) = f(t_i)$. I understand why $\int g(x) = L(f,P)$ with the infimum definition, but I am not sure how to handle $g(t_i) = f(t_i)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that

$$
\int_a^b g(x)dx \;\; =\;\; \sum_{i=1}^n g(t_{i-1})(t_i - t_{i-1}) \;\; =\;\; \sum_{i=1} \inf_{t \in [t_{i-1}, t_i]} f(t) (t_i - t_{i-1}) \;\; =\;\; L(f,P). 
$$

We can skip directly to a summation when integrating $g$ since it is a step function.  Plugging in our expression for $g$ in terms of $f$ reveals the lower sum for the integral.

**Edit:**
The reason why you can take $g(t_i) = f(t_i)$ is because, as you've defined it, for $x \in (t_{i-1}, t_i)$ you have that

$$
g(x) \;\; =\;\; \inf_{t \in [t_{i-1}, t_i]} f(t).
$$

The subtlety here is that you're defining $g$ on an open interval but you're taking the infimum of $f$ on a closed interval, which doesn't violate anything.  You then have that $g$ is constant on $n$ disjoint open intervals, and then $g(t_i)$ will present at most $n$ discontinuities if $f$ doesn't obtain a local minimum at $f(t_i)$, and this still allows $g$ to be Riemann integrable.

Comment: Hi thanks, could you take a look at the comments and answer my question if you can please.

Comment: @DH. I edited my post, let me know if it answers your question or if you're still having trouble with it (or if my answer is wrong!).

Comment: I think you meant $g(t_i)$ will agree with $\inf ..$ or $f(t_i)$ but I think I get it now, thank you so much

Comment: @DH. Yes, you're right.  I was overcomplicating it with the last bit.  I think my answer should be consistent now.